# Wrong results of dual variables

Tags: python, pyomo

I have following code:

```
for v in model.component_objects(Var, active=True):
    varobject = getattr(model, str(v))
    for index in varobject:
        if isinstance(varobject[index].domain, IntegerSet) or isinstance(varobject[index].domain, BooleanSet):
            varobject[index].fixed = True

results = opt.solve(model, tee=True)         variables
```

The integer variables have been fixed after a first run, so it is possible to get the dual variables. The problem is that the values for the dual variables I get for one of the constraints differ from the ones I get using gams for the same model and data. Even though I get the same values for the different variables. Does anybody have an idea what I could have done wrong? Thanks in advance!

Function to generate the output:

```
def generate_output(df, file, variable, indices, column_name):
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file, engine='xlsxwriter')
    df_copy = df[(df[list({'variable_name': variable})] == pd.Series({'variable_name': variable})).all(axis=1)].drop('variable_name', 1)
    mindex = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df_copy['variable_index'], names=indices)
    df_copy = pd.DataFrame(df_copy[['value']].values, index=mindex, columns=[column_name]).unstack('hour').reset_index()
    df_copy.to_excel(writer, 'Tabelle1')
    writer.save()
    wb = op.reader.excel.load_workbook(file)
    sh = wb['Tabelle1']
    sh.delete_rows(3, 1)
    wb.save(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solver convention differences could be at play, or slight variances in the tolerance values.

To test this, do you get the same result if you use the Pyomo model with a GAMS solver? `SolverFactory('gams').solve(model, tee=True, solver=???)`

Comment: I tried to test it like you suggested, but now I get following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\kernel\component_map.py", line 97, in __getitem__
    return self._dict[id(obj)][1]
KeyError: 2010165546248

I did not get this problem using Gurobi or GLPK..

Comment: Yes when I am generating the output I am copying the Dataframe with the results so that I can put them in a nice format. I put the function I am using to change the output in the description of the problem so it is better to see for you.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar issue on the value of dual variable.

I have contrasted the results obtained from Fico Xpress client/terminal and from pyomo model using Xpress solver (opt = SolverFactory("amplxpress")) and Gurobi solver (opt = SolverFactory("gurobi")).

In Fico Xpress, the dual associated with equality constraint is >=0, the dual associated with >= constraint is >=0 while the dual associated with <= constraint is <=0.

In Pyomo, I found the dual associated with equality constraint is still >=0, however the dual associated with inequality constraint(>=0 or <=0) is always <=0.

The dual of my desired equality constraint does not differ too much (the magnitude of difference may depend on model), while the dual of my desired inequality constraint differs quite a lot (vary largely by both magnitude and sign), however, it **might not** indicate the dual from pyomo is **necessarily incorrect**.

I am using the dual associated with inequality constraint as price (should be >=0) to calculate the some income/profit, where the equation I used in Fico Xpress is based on non-negative dual. As the pyomo gives me non-positive dual, I manimulate the equation and get the identical result even if the dual values from pyomo are completely different from Fico Xpress.

As dual associated with your model might has specific physical implication, have you checked the correctness of the result you want to get by manipulating dual before stuck into comparing the dual value?